# The Wicked wizard gem ignores my steps and jumps to request_steps/wicked_finish

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-gem

I'm using the [wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked)
After I hit RequestStepsController#update, I'm being redirected to /request_steps/wicked_finish. I have no idea why. Any suggestions?
If it worked as I expected it to, then the next step after updating the object would be :the_frame, as described in steps.

From the log:

```
  Started PUT "/request_steps/77" for 127.0.0.1

  Processing by RequestStepsController#update as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXX", "request"=>{"background_information"=>"prefilled"}, "commit"=>"C
  7"}

  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/request_steps/wicked_finish

  Started GET "/request_steps/wicked_finish" for 127.0.0.1
  Processing by RequestStepsController#show as HTML
    Parameters: {"id"=>"wicked_finish"}
  Completed 404 Not Found in 180ms

  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Request without an ID:
```

This is my RequestStepsController

class RequestStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard

```
steps :background_information, 
  :no_list_what_can_go_wrong,
  :the_frame,
  :select_group


def show
  @request = Request.find(params[:request])
  render_wizard
end

def update
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  @request.update_attributes(request_params)
  render_wizard @request
end

def request_params
  params.require(:request).permit(:title, :description, :goal, 
     :request_group_id, 
     :repository_url,
    :background_information
    )
end
```

end

This is my form:

```
= simple_form_for(@request, url: wizard_path(@request), method: :put, :html => { :class => 'form-inline span8 help_text' }) do |f|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(disclaimer: I did not read your complete question :))

The `render_wizard` method checks if it can save your `@request` object. If it **can** it will go to the next step and try to save it there.. and so on.. until the last step.

See the source code here: https://github.com/schneems/wicked/blob/master/lib/wicked/controller/concerns/render_redirect.rb#L17

To stop it from doing so you need to make sure your object can't be saved in the particular step. Something like described here: https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step

You could also use `render_step(params[:id])` instead of `render_wizard`.

Comment: Thanks, the Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step Wiki-page explains what I needed.